# Vb script for T-21 days (here T is current date)

Tags: vbscript, rpa, automationanywhere

Final out put like
Today date is 28-Apr-2021

Output like.but it should not include saturdays and sundays(only working days)
27-Apr-2021
26-Apr-2021
23-Apr-2021
Like this...

Comment: It would be nice to know what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to loop through dates and check the day of the week using [Weekday](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/weekday-function) function. This function returns a list of `daysToList` dates starting from yesterday, skipping weekends:

```
Function TMinus(daysToList)
    Dim daysFound
    Dim currentDay
    Dim list
    
    ' Initialize variables
    daysFound = 0
    list = ""
    currentDay = Now
    
    Do While daysFound < daysToList
        currentDay = DateAdd("d", -1, currentDay)
        Select Case Weekday(currentDay)
            Case 1, 7
                ' Skip weekends
            Case Else
                list = list & FormatDateTime(currentDay, 2) & vbCrLf
                daysFound = daysFound + 1
        End Select
    Loop
    TMinus = list
End Function
```

Answer (score -3):

I think I have just understood you.
What you want is that the output of the file should only be on working days.
Well, you can try this:

```
a = WeekDay("4/26/2021")
 
msgbox a
```

or this

```
a = WeekDay(Date)
 
msgbox a
```

You have to keep in mind that for Windows the day Sunday =1, Monday =2..... Saturday = 7
or you can also define which day of the week you want to be the first day of the week and play with that

Comment: Out put like this: 28-Apr-2021   27-Apr-2021 like its go on upto T-21 days(exclude sat and sundays)